# Scale and rotate 3D points with respect to axis of a different coordinate system

Tags: matlab, math, 3d, geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a set of 3D points in a coordinate system `B` which I want to rotate and scale by certain angle `theta` and certain scaling factor `scale` about each axis of coordinate system `B` and then transform them to a different coordinate system `A`. I know the `4x4` transformation which transforms points in coordinate system `B` to coordinate system `A`.

For example,

I have a transformation matrix

```
Tr =   [0.0065,0.9999,-0.0106,-5.0682
       -0.0105,-0.0105,-0.9999,1.7843
       -0.9999,0.0066,0.0105,8.6412
        0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0000]
```

Currently, I use `Tr` to transform 3D points from coordinate system `B` to `A`. 
However, I want to modify `Tr` (by multiplying additional matrices) such that, after transformation to `A` the points are rotated and scaled by `theta`, `scale` about each axis of of coordinate system `B'.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate - maybe with an example? Do you want to transform the points to B, perform the rotation and scaling, and transform back to A?

Comment: Is the set of 3D points an image? Do you want to rotate in `x,y` axes or `x,y,z` axes? If you want to rotate in 3D, you will need `theta1` and `theta2`

Comment: @NicoSchertler I start with points in B. I want to perform rotation and scaling about axis of B and then transform points to A. I have edited my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T_scale = [scale_x 0       0        0
           0       scale_y 0        0
           0       0       scale_z  0
           0       0       0        1]

T_i(theta) = [R_i(theta) [0; 0; 0]
              [0 0 0]    1        ]


T = Tr * T_scale * T_z(theta_z) * T_y(theta_y) * T_x(theta_x)
```

With `R_i(theta)` as defined by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 4×4 transformation matrices of `A` and `B` as

```
      | R_A  t_A |           | R_B  t_B |
T_A = |          |     T_B = |          |
      |  0    1  |           |  0    1  |
```

then to find  the relative transformation from `A -> B`

```
T_AB = inv(T_B)*T_A
```

this is interpreted as local-->global for `A` followed by a global-->local for `B`.